# Is there a way to transfer a free game downloaded on one Steam account to another?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I downloaded Team Fortress 2 for free yesterday off Steam. I used my account to download it. My brother has set up his own now and would like to play TF2 on his, that way we could also have separate profiles and scores. I don't want to re-download TF2 because we don't have much bandwidth. Is there a way to transfer the whole game over to his account?

Comment: Do you intend to play on the same computer or different computers?

Comment: Different pc's ;) sorry I never saw this question earlier... -_-

Comment: Related: [How can I copy/transfer games via external hard drive?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/59731/4797)

Answer (score 10):

**If you want to play on the same PC:**

Yes. Steam should recognise that the game is already installed. Failing that (which definitely works on games newer to Steam, but I'm unsure about older games like TF2), copy the contents of your SteamApps folder to his. (see the SteamApps\username instructions below)

**If you want to play on seperate PCs:**

Yes. Open your SteamApps folder. This will be depend on your operating system and be:

```
C:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps
```

for 32 bit (older) Windows systems,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps
```

for 64 bit (newer) Windows systems, and

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps
```

for Mac OS X systems.

You will need to copy all files who's name begins with "source" or "team fortress 2" from that folder on your PC to the folder on your brother's PC. There is also a file called `winui.gcf` which you will need to copy in there also.

Then follow the instructions in the below heading.

**`SteamApps\username` folder instructions**

You will also need to copy the `<your steam username>\team fortress 2` folder inside your SteamApps folder to `SteamApps\<your brothers steam username>\team fortress 2`. If there are any folders beginning with `source` or `winui` in there as well, you should copy those also. Apart from required files for the game itself, these folders contain configuration and downloaded maps.

**Notes**

If you miss any individual files then they will be downloaded when Steam launches the game.

These instructions will not work for Windows to Mac, or Mac to Windows.

Comment: It should also be noted that steam includes a nice backup utility within itself that could be used in place of copy-pasting a folder. It's under the Steam menu in the top-left corner, or I believe you can find it per-game with the right-click context menu.

Comment: The backup option is also safer in many instances than simply copy-pasting.

Comment: Ah yes, I'd forgotten about that, as the only times I do this are in bulk when I have to move Steam to a new PC, and for that the backup utility is extremely slow.

Comment: IIRC, regarding recognition of older games, my brother played TF2 on my computer several times, after it went free. He now plays it on his own PC, but back then, we didn't download nor copy anything more, he just used what I had downloaded for my account.

Comment: I added info about doing the same on Mac systems to your answer, and a couple other bits of information. Please feel free to revert or further edit if you disagree. (Also, I think I recall successful Mac⇔Windows copies of just the `.gcf` files, which are the majority of the download size, but I'm not certain.)

Comment: @KevinReid Made a small edit regarding the need for the team fortress 2 folder, but otherwise everything's fine.

Comment: I am reasonably certain that copying that folder is not *necessary* — Steam will download as needed — and if you copy that folder entire you copy configuration as well, which may be undesired for giving the files to a different player.

Comment: @Macha Thank you so much for your speedy reply, I really appreciate you taking your time to send a very detailed and accurate one :). In the end I used the back up option, all seems to be going well and steam is updating it TF2 here and there. :) Will comment back if all goes well and it works...

Comment: The game worked perfectly and transferred with no problems. Thank you for all your help :) :)