# Removing Skyrim's HD texture pack before finishing the entire download

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I saw the HD texture pack for Skyrim on Steam, so I went ahead and clicked install. One thing I forgot to check is the download size, which is important since my connection speeds are throttled if I exceed 9GB of bandwidth before the end of the month. Is there any way I can cancel the download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Steam Library Downloads page, you can pause and cancel active downloads. Also by right clicking on an entry in your Steam Library, you can do the same.

Unfortunately, because steam binds this form of DLC to your account, your options are limited. As long as Steam has the DLC bound to the game, it will try to install it. You can turn off Steam's automatic updates for Skyrim, but this means that you won't get any of the updates to Skyrim and even manual updating will try to install the DLC so this is not a long-term solution. **Your only real solution is to [contact Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/) and [have them remove the DLC from your account](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showpost.php?p=29647767&postcount=45).**

Comment: Really, that is lame.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to cancel the download or burn your one chance to a Steam refund for this. You just need a friend on an unfucked internet connection and then you can just use the [SneakerNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet).

- If he has Skyrim with HD textures, great. Otherwise, go there and log in with your account there.
- Download the game if necessary.
- [Make a Steam Backup of it.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59731/how-can-i-copy-transfer-games-via-external-hard-drive)
- Log out of your account if necessary.
- Put the backup on a sufficiently large thumbdrive or equivalent.
- Take it home.
- [Restore the backup on your machine.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59731/how-can-i-copy-transfer-games-via-external-hard-drive)

Answer (score -3):

The only way for me was to turn my internet off when I was playing Skyrim.