# Copy steam games to other PCs

Tags: steam

Some time ago it was very easy to copy steam game files. start the download, close steam and copy the files to steam/steamapps/common/.

But now this folder wont appear until the download has finished. It is in steam/steamapps/downloading/. Coping the files there wont solve the problem, because steam saves the progress in steam/steamapps/downloading/state__.patch files, which are not editable with a usual editor like gedit, MS editor or MS wordpad. Is there a workaround?

I want to copy the program files, not the progress in a game.

Comment: Are you asking how to share a save file to another computer? If so many steam games allow a cloud storage for accessing save files on different computers.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59731/how-can-i-copy-transfer-games-via-external-hard-drive

Comment: @sherby_ see edit

Comment: @JayLapham This is helpful, but it seems like the third party backup isn't working anymore and i cannot locate the mentioned clientregistry.blob

Comment: @Motte001 I see, I'll try and get back to you on that, as right now I do not have the answer. Did you check the steam discussions?

Comment: @Motte001 clientregistry.blob should be in the root steam folder, the same place as steam.exe. If you have multiple libraries, only the one with steam.exe will have that file.

Comment: @JayLapham Steam.exe is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam, but there is no clientregistry.blob. Is it in your latest version of steam?

Comment: Ah, mine is present but it's not used by steam anymore. You want to visit steam://flushconfig/ in your browser and if the steam:// protocol is registered it should flush the same data that was once contained in clientregistry.blob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following has worked for me on Windows without 3rd party tools.

First I install Steam in the new location (if it's not already installed), log in at least once, then exit. Then from the original Steam location, I copy over 2 things to the same relative directories in the new Steam location:

1. The game's directory in **\Steam\SteamApps\common\**

   (should be the name of the game, roughly)
2. The game's ACF file in **\Steam\SteamApps\**

   (*appmanifest_**APPID**.acf* where **APPID** is found [like so](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149837/how-do-i-find-the-id-for-a-game-on-steam))

Once those 2 things are copied over, log back into Steam and you should be set.

Comment: +1. This is what I do when I need to move games over. However, I usually only copy the folder in \common\ to the new \common\ folder. Then I open Steam again and try to install the game, which will have Steam discover the files that are already there.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to download a game and stop the progress, it creates the file/folder structure required. Close steam as an appication, then once you copy over the game from **\Steam\SteamApps\common** then you need to find the config file (normally, just look based on the time/date stamp on the files under **\Steam\SteamApps** - it will probably be the latest file created) then you need to open the config file via notepad and change the "StateFlags" to > "4"; Then re-open steam - and it will re-validate the game files, easy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).